# remove a word from string if it exists in txt file in python

Tags: python

Hey so I would like to remove a word from my string if this specific word is in my text file.
is this possible without storing my whole file in a list

```
removable_words # in this case is a txt file 
text = [w for w in text.split() if w not in removable_words]
```

Comment: You will either need to go over the file N times (very costly) or at least store all words in memory once.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Reading removable_words from a file? or removing words from a string?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using string.replace(target,replacement) for this.

First you need to read contents of .txt file that you have([like this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/)).
I assume your txt looks something like this :

Word1,Word2,Word3,Word4

Once you have converted .txt file content into an array you can do something like this :

```
for word in removable_words:
  text.replace(word,"") // This will replace word with empty string
```

Comment: This will replace `word` if it's a substring of a word, not the whole word.